# How to replace document.QuerySelector with $ without getting table.deleteRow is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use

```
const table = document.querySelector('table#home');
```

then the following code works ok

```
const streetRowCount = $('table#home input[id^=street-]').length;
const offsetForZeroIndex = 1;
streetRowCount > 2 &&
  (table.deleteRow(skipFields + streetRowCount - offsetForZeroIndex))
}
```

However when I replace `document.querySelector` with jquerys `$`, i.e.

```
const table = $('table#home');
```

I get an error

```
table.delete_row is not a function`
```

Comment: `const table = $('table#home')[0];` would work but thats just bad practice

Answer (score 4):

`table` is now a jQuery object, and they do not have a `delete_row()` method (or even a [`deleteRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow) method, as that's the correct name)

Instead you need to `find()` the row within the table at the given index and `remove()` it, like this:

```
const $table = $('table#home');
$table.find('tr').eq(skipFields + streetRowCount - offsetForZeroIndex).remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

[HTMLTableElement.deleteRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow) is vanilla JavaScript method, you can not use that on jQuery referenced element. You can use [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) instead.