# How can I replace my document.querySelector with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I was able to replace my

```
document.getElementById
```

with

```
$(po.homeStreets)
```

where `homeStreets` is the string

```
po.homeStreets = 'table#home tr input[id^=home-street-]'
```

However when I try and do a similar action to replace

```
po.home= 'table#home';
const table = document.querySelector(po.home);
                 ^         ^
```

(which works), with

```
po.home= 'table#home';
const table = $(po.home)
                ^    ^
const newRow = table.insertRow(skipFields + lastRowNum);
```

I get an error:

```
table.insertRow is not a function
```

The source HTML has 3 tables for id's `#home`, `#billing` and `#submit`

Comment: Because `.insertRow` is not a jQuery method (which the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/insertRow) would have told you) -> [jQuery Learning Center -> Manipulating Elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/)

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that even though there is only 1 match for the identifier I still get an array back, thanks.

Comment: Didn't you [ask this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002166/how-to-replace-document-queryselector-with-without-getting-table-deleterow-is)?

Comment: Yes, many times.  I forget which multiverse I am reliving, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select an element with jQuery, it returns the DOM element wrapped in a [jQuery object](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-object).

jQuery objects do not have the `insertRow` method (which belongs to [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)). You can do:

```
const table = $(po.home)
const newRow = table[0].insertRow(skipFields + lastRowNum);
```

Comment: Works, thanks.  I prefer the first to be `const table = $(po.home)[0]` what do you think ?

Comment: Yeah, it will also work. Take into account that you are using jQuery and then getting the HTML element. Why not stick with the code you had at the beginning?